# Prevent NavigationView from automatically highlighting selections

Tags: android

I decided to add the support design library

```
 compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
```

to my gradle, to allow me to implement

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
```

Without crashing.

My issue is that I was using navigation view to allow users to select items from sub groups which would show what they have (filters mostly), but now what I am selecting is randomly vanishing, and selecting items that I do not want to just because they are tapped.

Before I achieved this by doing this

```
   selection.setIcon(R.drawable.radio_button_off);
   selection.setChecked(false);
   item.setIcon(R.drawable.radio_button_on);
   item.setChecked(true);
```

On whatever item was tapped. Is there a way to prevent navigation view from automatically assigning the checked highlights? Or any alternatives methods? thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping you already added NavigationItemSelectedListener to select the item. If yes and still facing the issue, then please share your code for further info.

Cheers!!!

Comment: Yes the code shown is what is executed as a result of that. Item is the menu item tapped, and selection is the previous